# how to change the location of controls in TableLayoutPanel control at runtime in vb.net windows form

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a TableLayoutPanel control in Windows Form. Now I have 4 Panel controls in that TableLayoutPanel as Panel1 in cell(0,0), Panel2 in cell(0,1), Panel3 in cell(1,0) and Panel4 in cell(1,1).

Now I want to move Panel4 at Panel1 and hide Panel1. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TableLayoutPanel` supports the [`GetCellPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcellposition(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`SetCellPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcellposition(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to interacted with the child control locations.

The following method can be used to swap the location of two child controls.

```
Private Shared Sub SwapPosition(c1 As Control, c2 As Control)
    Dim tlp As TableLayoutPanel = TryCast(c1.Parent, TableLayoutPanel)
    If tlp Is c2.Parent AndAlso tlp IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim posC1 As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = tlp.GetCellPosition(c1)
        Dim posC2 As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = tlp.GetCellPosition(c2)

        tlp.SetCellPosition(c2, posC1)
        tlp.SetCellPosition(c1, posC2)
    End If
End Sub
```

As far as hiding a child control, either remove it from the `TableLayoutPanel`'s Control collection or call the `Hide` method on the control.

Answer (score 2):

If you move your panels out of the TableLayoutPanel at *design* time (i.e. Move them onto the Form surface somewhere), and then add them to the tlp control at *runtime*, you can add and remove controls at will.

This relies on each square of the layoutpanel being occupied because when you call `Controls.Add` it Docks into the *next* available space.

So add all your panels at runtime:

```
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Panel1)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Panel2)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Panel3)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Panel4)
```

The you can use this method to swap controls:

```
Private Sub SwapControls(aTableLayoutControl As TableLayoutPanel, firstControl As Control, secondControl As Control)
    aTableLayoutControl.Controls.Remove(firstControl)
    aTableLayoutControl.Controls.Remove(secondControl)
    aTableLayoutControl.Controls.Add(secondControl)
    aTableLayoutControl.Controls.Add(firstControl)
End Sub
```

So by calling this it should give you what you want:

```
    SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, Panel1, Panel3)
    Panel1.Visible = False
```

Comment: Try running the code please.  You can tell it is not correct because you don't say exactly in what row and column the control needs to appear.

Comment: This is working code @HansPassant - I have modified the first paragraph so it should now be clearer.

Comment: hi @matt-wilko, It is working but why do I keep the controls out side of  TableLayoutPanel. I want to keep the controls in TableLayoutPanel at design view. Now at run time I want to move controls any where in the TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: @OmPrakashGupta - when I tried this with the controls inside the layout, removing them and re-adding them put them back to their original position so it didn't solve the problem